# Rails If- Elseif- Else shorthand

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails I know to represent If-Else shorthand is this

```
if a==b 
 do_something(a)
else 
  do_something(b) 
end
```

shorthand `a==b ? do_something(a) : do_something(b)`

How do I represent this in and `if-elseif-else` statement?

```
if a==b 
 do_something(a)
elsif a==c 
  do_something(c)
else
  do_something(b) 
end
```

Comment: You don't. Trying to make that any shorter is just going to make it less readable, why would you want to do this?

Comment: needs to b done in my view bcos i need to assign css class to a particular label and this is my only clean option of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
(a == b) ? do_something(a) : (a == c) ? do_something(c) : do_something(b)
```

Or

```
(a == b) ? do_something(a) : ((a == c) ? do_something(c) : do_something(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite accurate to call that shorthand. That is the [ternary operator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), which represents a conditional. There is no elsif version.

As for making the code cleaner, if you have a lot of elsifs, a case statement will read better

```
case a
when b then do_something
...
end
```

And my personal favorite, wrap your conditional in a intent-revealing private method, or if it's complex enough, it's own object!

Comment: Private method is out then, but I would still recommend putting it in a method somewhere instead of having complex conditionals in your view.